# Is there a way to ensure that the signer has generated a valid (message, signature) pair without seeing the message?

Tags: signature

Suppose Alice sends message $Enc(k_{AB}, m)$ to Bob where $k_{AB}$ is the common symmetric key. Next Alice sends a signature of $H(m)$ $\sigma_{sk_A}(H(m))$ signed under her private signing key $sk_A$ to Eve, where H is a secure hash function. Then, Bob decrypts the message and sends it to Eve where she verifies it with the signature. Here, either Alice or Bob can be malicious. If Bob is malicious, he gives the wrong message $m'$ to Eve, she can easily check this since the signature won't be valid. But if Alice is malicious and generates a garbage signature (or signature of some other message m''), is there a way for Eve to catch her?

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography.SE. It seems that you are asking for your HW. While we only provide hints to those, we first want to see what you tried. Could you [edit] your Qs and show your progress?

Comment: Since this could be homework, I'll only provide a hint: in order to catch alteration of a message, we need a reference. The only way to "catch Alice" would be to show that she changed the message $m$ between the computation of $\operatorname{Enc}(k_{AB},m)$ and the computation of $\sigma_{sk_A}(H(m))$. Assuming Eve can do this, and $k_{AB}$ is random and unknown to Eve, what can be concluded about $\operatorname{Enc}$?